# Pydev/eclipse : After import from GIT, can not set as pydev project

Tags: python, eclipse, git, pydev

I am running Eclipse Luna on a windows 64bits system, and installed pydev plugin, using python 2.7.8 as interpreter.
I imported a project from GitHub. Once this done, did right-click on the project, then:

```
pydev/Set as pydevproject
```

then once more right-click on the project, then:

```
pydev/Set as source folder (add to PYTHONPATH)
```

When I did this on other installation, in the package explorer the python package icons used to change from a "directory" icon to a "package" icon. But this time it did not happen.

The status is

- I can run the python files from eclipse ok
- but if I go on a package, perform right click then select "new", I do not have "module" in the list of possible options, but I am presented with the usual java related list (Java project, project, class ...)

Anything I could do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you're using the Java Package Explorer, not the PyDev Package Explorer... If you go to the PyDev perspective (window > open perspective), you can activate the PyDev perspective which'll already show it to you... or you can go to window > show view > pydev > pydev package explorer.